# Conflicting results when grouping observations in Stata vs Python

Tags: python, sql, stata

I have a longitudinal dataset and I am trying to create two variables that correspond to two time periods based on specific date ranges (period_1 and period_2) to be able to analyze the effect of each of those time periods on my outcome.

My Stata code for grouping variables by ID is

```
gen period_1 = date_eval < mdy(5,4,2020) 
preserve 
collapse period_1=period_1 
count if period_1
```

and it gives me a number of individuals during that period.

However, I get a different number if I use the SQL query in Python

```
evals_period_1 = ps.sqldf('SELECT id, COUNT(date_eval) FROM df WHERE strftime(date_eval) < strftime("%m/%d/%Y",{}) GROUP BY id'.format('5/4/2020'))
```

Am I grouping by ID differently in these two codes? Please let me know what you think.

Comment: This is unfortunately too optimistic that you will reach people fluent in Python and Stata able to work out mentally what each code chunk will do. On Cross Validated I underlined the need for a **minimal reproducible example** and that advice stands. You should Google that if you don't know what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Nick that a reproducible example would have been useful. Or at least a description of the results and how it is not as you expected. However, I can still say something about your Stata code. See a reproducible example below, and see how your code always results in the count 1. Even though the example below randomize the data to be different each time.

```
* Create a data set with 50 rows where period_1 is dummy (0,1) randomized
* differently each run
clear
set obs 50
gen period_1 = (runiform() < .5)

* List the first 5 rows
list in 1/5

* This collapses all rows and what you are left with is one row where the value
* is the average of all rows
collapse period_1=period_1 

* List the one remaining observation
list 

* Here Stata syntax is probably not what you are expecting. period_1 will
* here be replaced with the value in the first row. The random mean around .5.
* (This is my understanding assuming it follows what "display period_1" would do)
count if period_1

* That is identical to count if .5. And Stata evaluates 
* any number >0 to "true" meaning the count where 
* this statement is true to 1. This will always be the case in this code
* unless the random number generator creates the corner case where all rows are 0
count if .5
```

You probably want to drop the row with `collapse` and change the last row to `count if period_1 == 1`. But how your data is formatted is relevant for if this is the solution to your original question.

Comment: Dear Nick and ThelceBear, thank you for your help!